# get parameters from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-referer

I want to get a value from the http_referer in the same/similar way you'd get it from a request:

```
$this->_getParam('order', 0);
```

I thought I'd try something like this:

```
$lastrequest = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$lastorder = $lastrequest->getParam('order', 0);
```

But that doesn't work. There are no parameters. getParams returns an empty string. What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` looks like? Is there no data in $lastrequest?

Comment: Of course there is. It might look like this: http://domain.com/module/controller/action/param1/data/param2/data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally a bad idea.

On top of what [Justin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185494/get-parameters-from-serverhttp-referer/4185505#4185505), it's easier to just pass those values on to the new page directly rather than trying to parse them from the referrer.

Comment: @sims: It's Monday morning here.  I'm surprised my brain is even working. ;)  Then again looking at, thinking about, and sometimes answering SO questions can be a good warm-up before I actually get to my daily work.

Answer (score 2):

From the [PHP docs for HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

So keep in mind this parameter may not even be set by the browser...